# Combine 2 codes for Color and Center text . is it possible?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make simple code but making it look pretty :D
i want to combine these to codes if possible but i don't know how

```
call :ColorText 0a "Green"
set "Center=Code Options" & call :CenterText Center strLen
```

each work separately fine but i want to combine both to make the text centered and colored

edit

i want to make text "Code By ZeE" is to be green colored
this is the code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
title New Title
:: color 2
mode 120,30
set "cmdwidth=120"  
cls             
echo.                               
:Display
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.                               
echo.               
set "Center=-----------------------------" & call :CenterText Center strLen
set "Center=Code By ZeE" & call :CenterText Center strLen
set "Center=-----------------------------" & call :CenterText Center strLen
Call :ColorText 0a "lol"
echo.
pause               


:CenterText
  if not "!%1:~%len%!"=="" set /A len+=1 & goto :CenterText
(endlocal & set %2=%len%)
goto CenterTextDisplay
:AddSpace
set "spaces=%spaces% "
goto :eof
:CenterTextDisplay
set /a "indent=(cmdwidth - strLen)/2" 
set "spaces= "
for /l %%a in (1,1,%indent%) do call :AddSpace
echo %spaces%%Center%
set "len=0"
goto :eof
:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

Comment: `call :ColorText 0a "Green"&call :CenterText Center strLen` could work. If not then consider sharing  code of `:ColorText` and `:CenterText` procedures.

Comment: call :ColorText 0a "Green" will show the word green in color 0a but i want to show the centered code options with the color 0a i tried combine both calls but only 1st one will work other won't have effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `:CenterText` procedure, change

```
  echo %spaces%%Center%
```

to

```
if "%~3" == "" (
  echo %spaces%%Center%
) else (
  Call :ColorText %~3 "%spaces%%Center%"&echo(
)
```

Then, adding a third parameter (color code) to the `:CenterText` procedure **call** could help:

```
set "Center=Code By ZeE" & call :CenterText Center strLen 0a
rem                                                       ^^
```